# xubuntu: compiz using 100%+ cpu

Tags: xubuntu, virtualbox, compiz, cpu

I seem to be experiencing an issue with Compiz in terms of cpu usage.  <del>The only thing I've been doing differently (been running this system for a month or two with no issues) is I have been running virtualbox for a windows environment inside my xubuntu host.</del>  What I'm seeing happen is:

- Boot up, all is well
- <del>Open virtual box, all seems well here too</del>
- I use multiple work spaces, so I'm often switching around, and this is when I typically notice that things are now frozen.

At some point, I'll switch to a workspace, and find that things are unresponsive.  I can usually still use the mouse, but nothing really responds after this point. Drop to tty1, run top and compiz is using 100% cpu.  Any attempts to kill the compiz process doesn't really do anything (IE kill, pkill, killall, etc...).  It won't die.  restart lightdm and repeat the process.

Some stats if they are helpful:

```
greg@zero-cool:~$  lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti] (rev a2)

greg@zero-cool:~$  glxinfo | grep render
direct rendering: Yes
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GTX 750 Ti/PCIe/SSE2
    GL_KTX_buffer_region, GL_NVX_conditional_render, GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info, 
    GL_NV_compute_program5, GL_NV_conditional_render, 
    GL_NV_parameter_buffer_object2, GL_NV_path_rendering, 
    GL_KTX_buffer_region, GL_NVX_conditional_render, GL_NVX_gpu_memory_info, 
    GL_NV_compute_program5, GL_NV_conditional_render, 
    GL_NV_parameter_buffer_object2, GL_NV_path_rendering,
```

I can provide my xorg log too, if that would be helpful.  Thanks so much for reading, hopefully I can find out what is causing my CPU to peg and bring everything to a halt.  One thing of note, I use Vagrant for development, and I have not had any issues running virutalbox in a headless state, it just seems to be when I run that windows guest (for photoshop, fireworks, etc...) that I'm seeing this issue.

**EDIT:**

I initially thought this was related to Virtualbox, but I just experienced the same issue without using Virtualbox.  So now it's just seems to be that compiz will randomly (in that I haven't been able to detect an event that causes it) begin using 100% cpu and I have to restart lightdm which kills my previous session and I have to reopen everything again...sigh.